Adding mouse tracking data over image in ReactJS
I use JS to have people draw an image using the mouse. I capture a PNG of their final product along with the mouse tracking data. I now want to display the final image and overlay the mouse tracking info on it in ReactJS.
I am able to display the raw PNG image using:
<img id="Replay Image" src={value} alt="Sketchpad screenshot"></img>

I would like to add my mouse tracking info on top of this image.
I am also willing to display the image on my page and when the user clicks on the image it opens in a new page and then I add the mouse data. The problem here is that I cannot figure out how to send the raw image data to the new window.
Any help would be great. Thank you
I have tried to get the image position using document.getElementbyID("Replay Image"), then use this info to start drawing my mouse info. This does not work because when the page loads, the image is off the screen and the user needs to scroll down to see it.

Create a canvas, draw the image on that, draw the mouse data on top of that, and then turn that into an image source using canvas.toDataURL?

To overlay mouse tracking data on an image in ReactJS, you can use the  element to draw the image and then overlay the mouse tracking data.
Create the Canvas Component
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const MouseTrackingOverlay = ({ imageSrc, mouseData }) => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const image = new Image();

    image.src = imageSrc;
    image.onload = () => {
      // Set canvas dimensions to match the image dimensions
      canvas.width = image.width;
      canvas.height = image.height;
      
      // Draw the image on the canvas
      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

      // Draw the mouse tracking data
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      mouseData.forEach((point, index) => {
        if (index === 0) {
          ctx.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
        } else {
          ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
        }
      });
      ctx.stroke();
    };
  }, [imageSrc, mouseData]);

  return <canvas ref={canvasRef}></canvas>;
};

export default MouseTrackingOverlay;

Use the MouseTrackingOverlay component in your main component. Pass the image source and mouse tracking data as props.
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import MouseTrackingOverlay from './MouseTrackingOverlay';

const App = () => {
  const [imageSrc] = useState('path_to_your_image.png');
  const [mouseData] = useState([
    // Example mouse tracking data
    { x: 10, y: 20 },
    { x: 50, y: 60 },
    { x: 80, y: 100 },
    // Add more points as needed
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Mouse Tracking Overlay</h1>
      <MouseTrackingOverlay imageSrc={imageSrc} mouseData={mouseData} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

If you want to open the image in a new window and overlay the mouse tracking data there, you can send the image data and mouse tracking data through the URL or use window communication methods like 'postMessage'.
Receive the data and render the component.
In the new window script, you can listen for the message and render the component
This approach will allow you to open a new window and pass the image data along with the mouse tracking data to it. The new window will render the image with the mouse tracking overlay.

I am amazed at the clarity of this response. Thank you, it worked exactly as you described.
